# The expected height of a randomly filled binary search tree on n distinct keys is O(log(n))

Tags: binary-search-tree, computer-science

I am working on a project for school, and the assignment has us:

1. Implement the Tree-Insert(T,z) operation on a binary search tree.
2. Repeatedly Insert n randomly picked numbers in a binary search tree and collect the height *h.*
3. Plot on the same plot the quantity *h/lg(n)* versus *n.*

I have a completed program that outputs the value of *n* from 250-50K, the average height of my randomly filled BST, and the value of *height(n)/log<sub>2</sub>(n).*  I can provide the code if needed but the pseudocode for the program looks like:

```
collectData()
for n = 250 to 10,000 by 250 // 250, 500, 750, …. 10,000
    sum_heightn = 0
    for j = 1 to 10 do //Take 10 measurements mj for j=1 to 10
        for i = 1 to n
           pick randomly a number p in the range [0,n]
           create a node z
           set z.key = p
           Tree-Insert(T,z)
        Measure the height hj of the tree
        Discard Tree
        sum_height += hj
collect Height(n)= sum_heightn/10 // Average height for n
Write in a file F the value n and Height(n)/log_2(n).
```

I am struggling trying to understand what the value I get when calculating *h(n)/log<sub>2</sub>(n)* means.  Can anyone help explain?  Thanks.

Comment: I forgot to mention, the data plot I have for values of n (x-axis) from 250-50K and h(n)/log(n) (y-axis) appears to be constant at about 2.3.

Comment: A randomly filled binary search tree can be skewed and so it's height can go up to `n` (when the order of insertion is either increasing or decreasing). `h(n)/log_2(n)` the more this number approaches `1` from the right side, the more it means that the constructed tree is balanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A binary tree of height `h` can have at most `2^h - 1` nodes.

```sh
     1
    / \
   /   \
  2     3
```

The height of the above tree is `2`, and the maximum number of nodes that you can have in this tree is `2^2 - 1` = `3`.

`log_2(n)` for a large `n` denotes (approximately) the height of a completely filled tree. Similarly, you can say that asymptotically, the height of a balanced tree with `n` nodes will be `O(log_2(n))`.

`height / log_2(n)` is simply a ratio which can go

- maximum up to `n / log_2(n)` when the tree is skewed (when the order of insertion order is either increasing or decreasing).
- minimum up to `1` when the tree is perfectly balanced and the height of the tree becomes `log_2(n)`.

You can see this ratio in the following way: It depicts the degree of skewness of the given tree. If this ration is close to `n/log_2(n)`, then the tree is *very* skewed and if the ratio is close enough to `1`, then the tree is `much` balanced.